# С какой буквы пишутся названия игр?

Tags: орфография

Речь идет не о всяких настольных играх, а о таких общепринятых, как "казаки-разбойники", "дочки-матери" и т.д. Как правильно писать название этих игр: с большой буквы или с маленькой и нужны ли кавычки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Со строчной и без кавычек. Исключениями будут случаи когда в качестве названия игры используется слово в переносном значении, например, *играть в "ручеёк"*. Или если подчёркивается, что это именно название, *игра "пятнашки" имеет следующие правила...*